# Boto S3 python script error: ValueError: Filename must be a string

Tags: python, amazon-s3, syntax-error, boto3

I am relatively new to coding and trying to write a script that will look for certain filenames in a specific S3 bucket. If the file is available, it will be read in via pandas for minor edits, and then output as a new filename locally.

I am attempting to have the filename options as a function which I believe is ultimately causing the error below, but not certain. Any ideas on what in my code is causing this error and how to resolve it.

```
File "tester.py", line 23, in <module>
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(Key,filename)
File "/Users/b/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 168, in bucket_download_file
    ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
File "/Users/b/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 130, in download_file
    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
File "/Users/b/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 301, in download_file
    raise ValueError('Filename must be a string')
ValueError: Filename must be a string
```

My full code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import fnmatch
import os
import time
import boto3
import botocore

bucket_name = 'data' # replace with your bucket name
Key = 'Setting/incoming/' # replace with your object Key
date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')


def filename(file):
        Accountfile = "accountteam_table.csv"
        Subscript = "subscription.csv"
        Opportunity = "opportunity.csv"
        Subtable = "subscription.csv"
        Opttable = "opportunity.csv"
        Accounttable = "account.csv"

try:
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(Key,file)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        path = s3.Bucket(bucket_name,Key)
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, Accountfile):
                df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
                df.drop_duplicates(subset= 'Account Team Member Id', keep='first', inplace=True)
                df['date_added'] = ""
                df.to_csv('accountteam_table_'+ date + '.csv', sep=',')

#subscription Product and Charge pre-process file

            elif fnmatch.fnmatch(file, Subscript):
                df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
                df.drop_duplicates(subset= 'Subscription Product & Charge ID', keep='first', inplace=True)
                df.drop('Opportunity Name','Account Name','Subscription Name', axis=1)
                df['date_added'] = ""
                df.to_csv('subscriptionproduct_charge_table_'+ date + '.csv', sep=',')

            elif fnmatch.fnmatch(file, Opportunity):
                df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
                df.drop_duplicates(subset= 'Opportunity Product Family: ID', keep='first', inplace=True)
                df.drop('Opportunity Name','Non-Recurring TCV (OPF) Currency', axis=1)
                df['date_added'] = ""
                df.to_csv('opportunityproductfamily_table_' + date + '.csv', sep=',')
```

Comment: can a filename end with slash?

Comment: what is `file`, by the way? you never defined it.